# Help: showing that $\sin x + \tan x > 2x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How do I show that $\sin x + \tan x > 2x$ if $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$?

By using **mean value theorem** 
Am i right ?

" Both functions are non negative on the specified interval. The derivative of 2x is 2 while the derivative of $\sin x + \tan x = \cos(x)+\frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$ which is clearly greater than or equal to $2$. Since $\sin x + \tan x = 2x$ at $x=0$ and $\sin x + \tan x$ is increasing faster than $2x$ for every value of $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\sin x + \tan x$ is greater than or equal to $2x$."

Comment: What you haven't explained is "$\cos(x)+1/\cos(x)^2$ is clearly greater than or equal to $2$". Otherwise your argument is basically fine. You should actually write some equality or inequality that says why you can make this derivative comparison (probably the easiest way would be the mean value theorem).

Comment: Thank u @Ian but can you tell me how exactly write some equality or inequality by using mean value theorem I'm confused

Comment: Sure: let $0<x<\pi/2$, then $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=xf'(c)$ where $0<c<x$, now $f'(c)>2$ for all $0<c<\pi/2$ so $f(x)>2x$. The part that I don't think is so obvious is showing that $f'(c)>2$ for $0<c<\pi/2$. That's easy while $\cos(x)<1/\sqrt{2}$, so for $\pi/4<x<\pi/2$, but what about the rest?

Comment: @Ian you're right first i should make sure that f'(c)>2  .. thanks again for your help

Comment: $\cos x + \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} > \cos x + \frac{1}{\cos x}$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$, and $u + \frac{1}{u} \geqslant 2$ for $u > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\cdots$$

$$\tan x =x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^5}{315}+\cdots$$

Adding them can reveal your result.

Comment: the coefficients to every term are $\geqslant 0$